# Tutorials on how to make generative NFT on the Ethereum blockchain using Blender 3D

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment

I’m looking for a tutorial that covers how to create generative art for the Ethereum blockchain using Blender 3D. I’ve only been able to find the coding portions but no tutorials on how to implement generative blender 3D art with the contracts.

Maybe it would be easier to start with photoshop layers and create an algorithm in the contract that randomly generates characters using the layers I create. Would this be easier to start and is there also any tutorials on this?

Comment: It would be very expensive to store 3d information on the chain. You could store the 3d models on a server and for each NFT token include the link in the metadata that goes to the 3d model.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on a Blender add on that can generate thousands of images or 3D models. It does this by reading your .blend file and creating a unique DNA strand for every possible NFT you can generate. It then randomly selects however many you desire (10000 lets say) and exports them as a rendered image, or a 3D model.

Now you have a collection of 10000 NFT images, or 3D models.

From there you would have to use a website like NFT-Maker Pro (NFT-Maker Pro only works on Cardano) for whatever blockchain you are working with to upload those images and mint the NFT tokens as people requests them. (You could create a script that mints them all at once, but the gas fees would start to add up really quickly.)

Using a minting website with an API would be ideal, you could then mint your NFTs whenever someone actually wants to buy them. There are a lot more complications that you would run into, but that would be the rundown of the fundamentals.

For more information about the Blend_My_NFTs Blender add on I'm currently developing please check out our Discord and Github page:

Discord: https://discord.gg/gnjYEK5XxQ
Github: https://github.com/torrinworx/Blend_My_NFTs